# How to extract information from a dataset and make it into a new dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset that has many column which that goes in this order: name in english, countries, degree of endangerment, number of speakers.

Under degree of endangerment, there are 4 degrees vulnerable, definitely endangered, severely endangered and extinct.

I want to sort the dataset into these categories and make it into its own dataset, still keeping the other data in other columns

[this image has the columns name on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A6eu.png)

Loading my dataset on jupyter notebook- this is as far as i got

`if os.path.isfile("data.csv"):
    filepath = "data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
df.head(300)`

but i think the code will look something like this:

```
vulnerable = df[]
```

Comment: Please go through the [pandas tutorials](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html) and [cookbook](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html).

Comment: Don't post dataframes as images, post as text.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want a dataframe for each of the   degrees of endangerment?

Here is an example for "vulnerable":

```
vulnerable_df = df[df['Degree of endangerment'] == 'vulnerable']
```

This is because

```
df['Degree of endangerment'] == 'vulnerable'
```

Gives a series of True or False dependent on whether it is equal to vulnerable or not. `df[series_of_true_or_falses]` returns a copy of the original dataframe that only contains the indexes that were `True` in the `series_of_true_or_falses`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what ojunk posted, another way is using [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Degree' : ['vulnerable', 'not vulnerable', 'endangered']})
vulnerable_df = df[df['Degree'].isin(['vulnerable'])]
```

Output:

```
       Degree
0  vulnerable
```

Outputs dataset containing vulnerable alone.